# What determines which strand of DNA is transcribed by RNA polymerase?

Tags: molecular-biology, transcription

DNA has two strands. How does the machinery of RNA transcription determine which one to transcribe?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'll keep this short and simple. The direction of transcription (which determines which strand is used as the template) is controlled by the promoter, which is a region of specific DNA motifs at the 5' end of a gene. RNA polymerase binds to the promoter, which orients it on the correct strand and in the correct direction, after which it can proceed to transcribe the gene.

[image: An animation of the process described above]

That great little animation is from [this](http://www.geneticsrus.org/Genes/genes1.php) website.

Answer (score 16):

To add to *canadianer*'s answer, in fact genes can be found on both strands of the DNA in most eukaryotic cells, in the sense that the sense and anti-sense strands are not always the same strand. The direction is therefore completely determined by the promoter. Furthermore, there are [bidirectional promoters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_(genetics)#Bidirectional_promoters_.28mammalian.29).

Comment: This is interesting +1!! Can you add a reference to the sense/anti-sense being not confined to a particular strand?

Comment: @AliceD I'm pretty sure that he/she is just referring to the fact that, along an entire chromosome (which has two strands), some genes will be found on one strand and some on the other. The terms sense and antisense are relative to a specific gene, not an entire chromosome. Sometimes, uncommonly, two genes will overlap on opposite strands at the same loci.

Comment: @AliceD that would be pretty much any genome paper or undergraduate text book, really.  For a visual overview, have a look at [this](http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg38&position=chr9%3A132847932-133136551&hgsid=446186492_oIKzgjzQjo9CUuDQypq6e5sWvCnB). You'll see genes in both directions, so on both strands (the direction is given by the arrows in the lines representing the genes).

Comment: @terdon, gosh I feel kind of..  erm,... dumb, but I have struggled with this concept for years. Thanks!!

Comment: @AliceD good grief, when did not knowing something not directly related to your field become a reason to feel dumb? Did I miss a meeting? My PhD was on gene prediction and genome annotation, so this is my bread and butter. Just don't ask me to describe the Krebs cycle :)

Comment: @terdon I have a BSc in Biochemistry. I left the field a decade ago and went into neuroscience. Honestly, I have struggled with this since the first time I started learning about DNA. It all didn't make sense. I honestly thought there was one coding strand, and the other was just a backbone for chemical stability..:-/ This post has enlightened me for sure. It all fell in place. Just here.